# Is there a problem if I don't setup google analytics in my website?

Tags: google-analytics

is there a problem if I don't setup google analytics in my website?

I have read lot of articles describing use of google analytics but I have not added it in my site.

In Cpanel I can check all things like stats, unique visitor etc and in google analytics its almost same but if I want sponsor for my site then is it necessary to have google analytics? or can cpanel stats be shown to sponsor?

Thanks for reading! I hope I get an answer!

Comment: It may blow up be carefull....

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question directly - no there is not a problem if you don't set up a google analytics account. Millions of websites don't use google analytics.

In this instance I would define "problem" as: google don't penalise websites for not using analytics.

Now my opinion - whilst it won't do you any harm to *not* have them, it doesn't do any harm *to have them* either. If it provides no additional information to your cPanel stats, then nothing lost (other than a bit of time)

Comment: GA can slow down the load time unless you ensure it is the last script to load just before the `</body>` tag.

Comment: @JP19 - The asynchronous tracking snippet was created expressly to prevent the behavior you've described: http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncTracking.html

Comment: GA is better than cpanel and other server based stats IMO. the level of reporting on pages, visitors, search keywords and so on is fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics can be very useful, but it is generally not required. Typically if you are showing ads for syndications (such as Google) then the ad is loaded from the syndicator each time, so they track hits that way.

There may be instances where someone requires you to provide numbers from Google Analytics, but those situation are atypical.

Answer (score -3):

I would set it up anyway.  It takes about 5 minutes and is a piece of cake.  Even if you don't use it, it won't hurt, and can only help the way Google views your website.

Comment: You're not explaining why it's good or bad.

Comment: I thought it was pretty much self explanatory. The more you expose yourself to Google, the better you are off seo wise.  When you use GAnalytics, you are sharing more of your site information with Google.  This is good for you.  It could bring pages up or down depending on the seo, bounce, loading times and retention rates of those pages.  But then you use that to your advantage to tweak those pages accordingly so they go up.  Using GAnalytics can only help you.

Comment: That is absolutely false. The search engine does not use a jot of information from Analytics.

Comment: No, it is absolutely true.  What I just said clearly explains why.  Just because you read it on a blog somewhere doesn't make it true.

Comment: It doesn't clearly explain it at all, or at least to me it doesn't. Surely google will already collect SEO and loading times when it crawls your site? It doesn't need analytics to gather this information. But I do agree with your statement that "But then you use that to your advantage to tweak those pages accordingly so they go up."